# FramerJS - Horizontal scrollbar with the scroll component

Tags: coffeescript, framerjs

I have created a scrollable area and i am trying to add a scrollbar underneath the images (the blue scrollbar in the linked image)

Code that i currently have for the scrollable area.

```
scroll = new ScrollComponent
opacity: 1.00
shadowBlur: 0
scroll.size = screen
Info.parent = scroll.content 
scroll.scrollVertical = false
```

[Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V6tE.png)

Comment: It is not clear as what problem or issue you have encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to make a scrollbar that moves with the scrolling and shows how far along the user has scrolled, right?
Here's some code how to do that:

```coffee
scrollbar.parent = scroll
# First make the width of the scrollbar relative to the size of the content.
scrollbar.width = (scroll.width / scroll.content.width) * scroll.width
# When the scroll is moved
scroll.onMove ->
    # Calculate the width that we should scroll over
    width = scroll.content.width - scroll.width
    # Calculate the percentage that has currently been scrolled
    percentage = scroll.scrollX / width
    # Calculate how much space there for the scrollbar to move in
    freeSpace = scroll.width - scrollbar.width
    # Set the position of the scrollbar relative to the free space and the percentage scrolled
    scrollbar.x = freeSpace * percentage
```

A full example is here: https://framer.cloud/QtcLD